# Formula for angular momentum of three particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, momentum

Is it possible to write the *relative* angular momentum of three particles as a vector product of **single** position vector and **single** position momentum? I think that relative angular momentum can be defined as total angular momentum minus centre of mass angular momentum. To simplify let's assume equal masses. For instance for two particles system the position vector is simply relative coordinate and the momentum vector is the conjugate of the relative coordinate:

$$ \mathbf L_r = \mathbf L_{tot} - \mathbf L_{cm}=\mathbf r_1 \times \mathbf p_1+\mathbf r_2 \times\mathbf p_2 - \frac{1}{2}(\mathbf r_1 + \mathbf r_2) \times(\mathbf p_1+\mathbf p_2)= \frac{1}{2}(  \mathbf r_1 -\mathbf r_2) \times (\mathbf p_1 - \mathbf p_2) $$

I originally came up to the question thinking about QM but a classical argument shouldn't be much different.

Comment: What do you find for three particles?

Comment: You know how to express $\vec L_\text{tot}$ and $\vec L_\text{cm}$ in terms of the positions and momenta, consequently you can write $\vec L_\text{r}=\vec L_\text{tot}-\vec L_\text{cm}$ in terms of the positions and momenta, for any number of particles. I'm not sure what kind of answer you are looking for, can you clarify?

Comment: @Puk I want to write it as a product of a single position vector times a single momentum vector, like in last parte of the formula for two particles

Comment: @CosmasZachos What do you mean?

Comment: You wrote a formula for two particles.  Did  you apply it to three?

Comment: @CosmasZachos yes but I could not reduce it to a single vector product

Comment: @CosmasZachos Yes it's clear, actually I asked this question because I wanted to understand why the l=0 state of three pions from neutral Kaon decay has even parity w.r.t the position of the position of the three particles seen form centre of mass frame. So this isn't clear yet, maybe I'll post another question later

Comment: In the center of mass, all three "classical" pions are in an S wave w.r.t. said center, so each term vanishes.

Comment: @CosmasZachos why are all three in S waves? Couldn't they have different angular momenta that add up to zero?

Comment: In principle, but such configurations are of much higher energy, quantum mechanically...

Comment: @CosmasZachos And can something be said about the parity of such configurations? Because for two particles all relative l=0 configurations should be even, am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right on that. But for three,  in c.o.m., I'd need to think it through for all cases, since ***L*** is an axial vector, and $\ell$ is linked idiosyncratically to its Casimir invariants.

Comment: Ok I understand thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got your own answer in your comment: the relative coordinate part only simplifies for two components. Expand all phase-space variables into an average piece and an excursion from it,
$$
\bar {\mathbf r}\equiv {1\over n}\sum_{i=1}^n {\mathbf r_i},  \qquad \leadsto  \qquad  {\mathbf r_i} \equiv \bar {\mathbf r} + \tilde {\mathbf r_i} \implies \sum_{i=1}^n \tilde {\mathbf r_i}=0, \\
\bar {\mathbf p}\equiv {1\over n}\sum_{i=1}^n {\mathbf p_i},  \qquad \leadsto  \qquad  {\mathbf p_i} \equiv \bar {\mathbf p} + \tilde {\mathbf r_i} \implies \sum_{i=1}^n \tilde {\mathbf p_i}=0.
$$
so that
$$ \mathbf L = \sum_{i=1}^n   \mathbf r_i \times \mathbf p_i=  {n}~\bar {\mathbf r}  \times \bar {\mathbf p}+  \sum_{i=1}^n  \tilde {\mathbf r_i} \times \tilde {\mathbf p_i},
$$
a celebrated expression: no cross terms.  Both terms in the sum of the second, excursion, term are identical, so they collapse to your simple product; but from 3 on, they do not; why should they? There are more independent relative/excursion coordinates.